# #1005 - Can't create table 'xxx.item' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I am creating Database for a Hotel and I am not able to create `"Item"` table.

The error shown is

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'xxx.item' (errno: 150)
```

Below are my SQL queries:

```
create table menu ( 
    menu_id INT 
  , menu_name varchar(100)
  , PRIMARY KEY (menu_id) 
); 

create table categories ( 
    categories_id INT 
  , category_name varchar(100)
  , PRIMARY KEY (categories_id) 
); 

create table menu_category_item ( 
    mci_id INT 
  , menu_id INT
  , categories_id INT 
  , item_id INT 
  , item_type INT
  , restaurant_id INT 
  , PRIMARY KEY (mci_id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (menu_id) 
      REFERENCES menu(menu_id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (categories_id) 
      REFERENCES categories(categories_id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) 
      REFERENCES restaurants(restaurant_id)
); 

create table item (
    item_id INT
  , item_name varchar(100)
  , item_price decimal
  , FOREIGN KEY (item_id) 
      REFERENCES menu_category_item (item_id)
);
```

Please help me out of this!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the structure of the database, you should have item_id as the primary key in the item table, then let the menu_category_item table reference that. Like:

```
create table item (
    item_id INT
  , item_name varchar(100)
  , item_price decimal
  , PRIMARY KEY (item_id));

create table menu_category_item ( 
    mci_id INT 
  , menu_id INT
  , categories_id INT 
  , item_id INT 
  , item_type INT
  , restaurant_id INT 
  , PRIMARY KEY (mci_id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (menu_id) 
      REFERENCES menu(menu_id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (categories_id) 
      REFERENCES categories(categories_id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) 
      REFERENCES restaurants(restaurant_id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (item_id) 
      REFERENCES item(item_id)
);
```

If I'm correct, your item table would contain the items, you would need a primary key there. And menu_item_category is basically matching items to menus, so there is where you add your foreign key.

Comment from @Adam below:

> As a rule: 1 - every table should have a primary key and 2 - foreign
>   keys should usually be against the primary key the target table. There
>   are exceptions, but those rules are good starting places for basic DB
>   design IMO

Comment: Thnks a lot Joshua.. I will try this.. I will redesign these two tables and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is all the SQL you're running, the problem here is that there's no `restaurants` table, so trying to create the `menu_category_item` gives error 150.

Since `menu_category_item` failed to create, then `item` can't reference it, so is also giving the 150 error.

This is detailed in the [InnoDB error codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html) under `ER_CANT_CREATE_TABLE`.

Comment: I have restaurant table in my database. Table menu_category_item is created with no errors. But i am getting error while creating ITEM table.

Comment: Add this to the end of the query `ALTER TABLE menu_category_item ADD INDEX menu_category_item (menu_category_item)` while creating `menu_category_item` table.

Comment: Then it wont give you an error while creating ITEM table

Comment: Thanks paras.. I will try this out.. Simon can u let me know about InnoDB command as i  nt able to get anything in InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a unique index/constraint on the target of a foriegn key (in this case menu_category_item.item_id so that it knows which row in the target table is referenced.  But i may be getting my SQL flavours mixed up

Comment: You mean to say that i should alter menu _category_item and make item_id as unique?

Comment: @GagandeepSharma No you can't do that since you may have an item on > 1 menus. You need to make item_id as the primary key for the item table. Check my answer.

Comment: See @Joshua Kissoon's answer.  As a rule: 1 - every table should have a primary key and 2 - foreign keys should usually be against the primary key the target table.  There are exceptions, but those rules are good starting places for basic DB design IMO.

Answer (score 0):

`menu_category_item.item_id` has no index defined.

It is required to police the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

Added this - `ALTER TABLE menu_category_item ADD INDEX menu_category_item (menu_category_item)`

```
CREATE TABLE menu_category_item ( 
  mci_id INT , 
  menu_id INT, 
  categories_id INT , 
  item_id INT , 
  item_type INT, 
  restaurant_id INT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (mci_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY (menu_id) REFERENCES menu(menu_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY (categories_id) REFERENCES categories(categories_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY (restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants(restaurant_id),

 ALTER TABLE `menu_category_item` ADD INDEX `item_id` (`item_id`)
);
```

Comment: There is no such column `menu_category_item` in the OP's table `menu_category_item`. Then this sounds like suggesting to add a new column and then `index` it.

Comment: BTW: Your `edit` on OP's posting have errors which were not there in the former version. You better to rollback it to edit `version 2`.

Comment: @Ravinder - Was a typo. Thanks :)

Comment: Might have missed something. Still I have rolled back to your version.